# Ansible: How do I configure a jump host without ssh keys?

Tags: passwords, ansible, ssh-keys, openssh

I've looked [to faq][1] , but there is no answer for my task.

How can I access to bastion (jump box) host using password with Ansible? We do not consider using SSH keys. How will SSH config (or Ansible config) be look like for this situation? 
For instance using SSH keys, the configuration looks like this:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@gateway.example.com"'
```

How to achieve the same result by using password?

Comment: Exactly the same way as you showed, but you will be prompted for a password once it will be requested. You also miss a link to your faq.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry. Here it is - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ProxyJump` ssh option which does not require netcat/nc to be installed on the jump host.

So in the `~/.ssh/config` file of the user you are using to run the Ansible commands, add something like this

```
Host jumphost
  HostName 1.1.1.1  # use actual ip address or fqdn

Host *
  ProxyJump jumphost
```

Comment: I didn't know that this option available starting from OpenSSH 7.3. Could you give any example playbook? Because this is good way (if netcat unaviable)

Answer (score 0):

In my `~/.ssh/config` file, I have configured the bastion host like this:

```
##### Private hosts access through bastion host #####
Host bastion-host
  HostName 52.13.2.54
  ForwardAgent yes

Host 10.10.*
  ProxyCommand ssh -q bastion-host nc -q0 %h %p
```

Then I can directly run the Ansible over the hosts in private subnet. Hope that might help you